# SQL - Counting Records By Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like my results to include records only where there is more than Tag Date per Debt Number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tag.tag_shrt_nm AS [Tag]
    ,cnsmr.cnsmr_idntfr_agncy_id AS [Borrower Number]
    ,CAST(cnsmr_pymnt_tag.cnsmr_pymnt_tag_assgn_dt AS Date) AS [Tag Date]
    ,cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id [Debt Number]
FROM         
    cnsmr INNER JOIN
    cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl ON cnsmr.cnsmr_id = cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl.cnsmr_id INNER JOIN
    cnsmr_pymnt_tag ON cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id =  cnsmr_pymnt_tag.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id INNER JOIN
    tag ON cnsmr_pymnt_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id INNER JOIN
    cnsmr_accnt ON cnsmr.cnsmr_id = cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id
WHERE     
    tag.tag_shrt_nm IN ('tRehab')
ORDER BY 
    cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id
```

Here there is more than 1 date per debt number so this is my desired output.

```
Tag         Borrower Number     Tag Date        Debt Number
tRehab      1000020234          2012-02-20      1089484
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-07      1089484
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-10      1089484
tRehab      1000020234          2012-02-20      1089487
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-07      1089487
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-10      1089487
```

Here there is only 1 debt number per tag date so this not what I'm looking for and should not be in the results.

```
Tag         Borrower Number     Tag Date        Debt Number
tRehab      1000020234          2012-02-19      1089484
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-07      1089485
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-10      1089486
tRehab      1000020234          2012-02-20      1089487
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-07      1089488
tRehab      1000020234          2012-04-10      1089489
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql) to find the debt numbers that have more than one date. See the simplified example below.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(TagDate date, DebtNumber int)

INSERT INTO #Test(TagDate, DebtNumber) VALUES
('01/01/2017', 1089484),
('01/02/2017', 1089484),
('01/01/2017', 1089485),
('01/01/2017', 1089486),
('01/01/2017', 1089487),
('01/01/2017', 1089488)

SELECT *
FROM #Test AS O
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Test WHERE DebtNumber = O.DebtNumber HAVING COUNT(TagDate) > 1)

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, as it requires only minimal modification to what you already have:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
         tag.tag_shrt_nm AS [Tag]
         ,cnsmr.cnsmr_idntfr_agncy_id AS [Borrower Number]
         ,CAST(cnsmr_pymnt_tag.cnsmr_pymnt_tag_assgn_dt AS Date) AS [Tag Date]
         ,cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id [Debt Number]
         ,COUNT(cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id) OVER(PARTITION BY cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id ORDER BY cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id) AS [Debt Number Count]
      FROM         
         cnsmr INNER JOIN
         cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl ON cnsmr.cnsmr_id = cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl.cnsmr_id INNER JOIN
         cnsmr_pymnt_tag ON cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id =  
         cnsmr_pymnt_tag.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id INNER JOIN
         tag ON cnsmr_pymnt_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id INNER JOIN
         cnsmr_accnt ON cnsmr.cnsmr_id = cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id
      WHERE     
         tag.tag_shrt_nm IN ('tRehab')
      ORDER BY 
         cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id) tA
WHERE tA.[Debt Number Count] > 1
```

I guess my only question is, are there situations where the same date will occur more than once for the same debt number? For instance, maybe two different borrower numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
DECLARE @TabA TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Tag VARCHAR(25), Borrower VARCHAR(25), TagDate DATE, DebtNumber VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @TabA
        ( Tag, Borrower, TagDate, DebtNumber )

  select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-02-20','1089484'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-07','1089484'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-10','1089484'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-02-20','1089487'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-07','1089487'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-10','1089487'

DECLARE @TabB TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Tag VARCHAR(25), Borrower VARCHAR(25), TagDate DATE, DebtNumber VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @TabB
        ( Tag, Borrower, TagDate, DebtNumber )

  select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-02-19','1089484'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-07','1089485'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-10','1089486'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-02-20','1089487'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-07','1089488'
union select 'tRehab','1000020234','2012-04-10','1089489'

SELECT * FROM @TabA TA 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TabA TA2 WHERE TA2.DebtNumber = TA.DebtNumber AND TA2.TagDate <> TA.TagDate AND TA.Id <> TA2.ID)


SELECT * FROM @TabB TA 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TabB TA2 WHERE TA2.DebtNumber = TA.DebtNumber AND TA2.TagDate <> TA.TagDate AND TA.Id <> TA2.ID)
```